# Angular 5 ngModel not working

Tags: javascript, angular, datetimepicker, timepicker

I am using ngModel directive to detect or change property when input value change.

I am using a bootstrap time picker to change input value/time.

below is my code:

```
<input type='text' class="form-control timepicker"   [(ngModel)]="time.start_time">
```

property change working fine if I change input value manually but when it is change from popup it does not detect any change so does not change property.
[image]

Comment: can you post some code?

Comment: does the popup have its own scope?

Comment: It's a third party jquery plugin.

Comment: ah you mean the datepicker popup, i thought it wasn't working when the whole datepicker was placed in a popup, so the question about scope

Comment: Consider using an Angular implementation of the Bootstrap components instead of the standard jQuery version, for example the one provided by [ng-bootstrap](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/home). It contains a [Timepicker component](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/timepicker/examples).

Comment: I have added a ( blur ) event to input field and then change property from component but I don't think It's the right way to change a nested property when you are in a loop.